# Rails Turbo-Stream update my div won't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hotwire-rails

I am trying to update a div in my page.

```
<div id="post_hidden_fields"></div>
```

I added my controller to the turbo_stream format code in order to update this div

```
respond_to do |format|      
            format.turbo_stream do
                render turbo_stream: turbo_stream.update("post_hidden_fields", 
                partial: "home/update_post_form", locals: {post_type: params[:post_type], url: params[:url]})
            end
            format.html {} 
        end
```

my home/update_post_form partial looks like that:

```
<div id="post_hidden_fields">
<input autocomplete="off" type="hidden" name='<%= "post[#{post_type}]" %>' value="<%= url %>">
```

When it runs I look on my network tab and the response to the method is:

```
<turbo-stream action="update" target="post_hidden_fields">
<template>
    <div id="post_hidden_fields">
        <input autocomplete="off" type="hidden" name='post[photo]' value="SOME_URL">
    </div>
</template>
```

Seems like the turbo-stream part runs ok but somehow the dom won't change. I am still getting my post_hidden_fields div empty, and not holding the hidden input that I am trying to add to it.

Comment: You shouldn't use `turbo_stream.update` because you're replacing the whole element and not just updating its content, so you should use `turbo_stream.replace` instead.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a partial for your input and add your input within the turbo_stream tag as

   ```
    <%= turbo_frame_tag :custom_form do %>
       # add your partial here partial here
       <%= render partial: "partial_path", locals: { ... } %>
    <% end %>
   ```
2. Now create a file against your action like `action.turbo_stream.erb`
3. Inside your `action.turbo_stream.erb` call out your `turbo_frame_tag` with a unique name, in my case which is `custom_form` and replace your partial with new values

   ```
     <%= turbo_stream.replace : custom_form do %>
       # replacing the partial with turbo
       <%= render partial: 'partial_path', locals: { ... } %>
     <% end %>
   ```

That will be all your DOM elements will be re-render with turbo_stream.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use "replace" instead of "update"
Example:-
<%= turbo_stream.replace("xyx", partial: "blah/blah") %>

```
render turbo_stream: turbo_stream.replace("post_hidden_fields", partial: "home/update_post_form", locals: {post_type: params[:post_type], url: params[:url]})
```